# Substitute variable in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am using simple standard SQL query to get the record count from a table and I want to store it in a variable so that i can use it later.

Reason is my table contains a huge data and I don't wanted to use the below query again.

```
select count(1) from mytable;
```

Also I don't want use `PL/SQL`, just looking for `SQL` statements.

I tried using the define keyword but I am unable to set the count in the define variable.

Please suggest how can I store it in variable.

---

Example :

```
DEFINE some_variable;

SELECT COUNT(1) into some_variable,sysdate as CLEANUP_START FROM TABLE_TEMP;

--offcourse this is not correct for simple sql statment.however i want to store it in variable.

DELETE from MY_TABLE where Primary_key in (select primary_key from TABLE_TEMP ); 

--around 10M records are deleting 

SELECT sysdate as CLEANUP_END FROM dual;

---There are such 10 delete statments on different tables.

---Spool the deleted record in csv file. 

spool output.csv

select 'RESULT' from dual;

---And at the last i want print the summary of the cleanup records.

select primary_key from TABLE_TEMP;

select some_variable||',Records is deleted from MY_TABLE' from DUAL; 

spool off;
```

Comment: Please post some sample code to explain where and how you intend to use this variable.

Comment: It sounds like performance is important here, but accuracy isn't as critical (the row count may change after the variable is populated).  Have you considered using the data dictionary instead?   eg `SELECT NUM_ROWS FROM USER_TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'MY_TABLE';`

Answer (score 2):

Don't use a substitution variable; use a bind variable. Below I show a screenshot from SQL*Plus to demonstrate how this works.

I declare a bind variable, `cnt`, of type `number`. Then I use an anonymous block (I use the SQL*Plus `exec` command for brevity and convenience) to count the rows from a table and assign the result to `:cnt`. (I count the rows in the table `all_objects`, but which table I use is irrelevant - count from whichever table you need to count from). Finally, I select this variable from `dual` to show its value, and to show how it can be used in any `select` (and any other SQL) statement.

```
SQL> variable cnt number
SQL> exec select count(*) into :cnt from all_objects

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.45
SQL> select :cnt from dual;

      :CNT
----------
     89814

1 row selected.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.00
SQL>
```

Comment: Thanks but still i am unable to use it SQL developer tool. :(
Able to run the anonymous  block but not the last statement.

Comment: @Amir - there is absolutely **zero** mention of SQL Developer in your question. I can't read what is not written.